# How to change the CodeRunner .class file creation from same working directory of the java file in vs code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-code-runner

I am currently using vs code to run my java files.
But when I use coderunner and run my java file it creates a .class file for every class in the same directory of my java file. Which gets messy how can I get rid of that?
I am ok with uninstalling the coderunner but in that case the java file errors doesn't show up properly and build fails.

[image: My VS Code]

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Code Runner and choose `Java: Create New Project` from **Command Palette**.

Create a no build tools project and coding in `.java` files which stored in folder `src`, then all the generated `.class` files will be stored in folder `bin` by default.

[image]

About the compilation errors, please post code snippets for further solution.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am running into the same issues. Once I install Code Runner, class files are no longer generated in the /bin directory. They are now created in the same directory as the Java source code (/src). After this, nothing works right! Is the consensus to not use Code Runner?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Test Runner for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-test) or  [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) extension both by Microsoft. Better would be to go with an extension pack.

[image]